# Ideas on how to fix the following scrolling behaviour when using UITableView and large titles with something in between them

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Messing around with large titles and UITableViews in `UIKit`.
I want to have a simple `UISearchBar` and `UISegmentedControl` at the top of the `UITableView` as well as large titles without the large title overlapping those controls when scrolling down.

Check out this very large gif:

[Unwanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYS6n.gif)

Layout Code is as follows - ommitting all the datasource and model stuff for the tableview content:

```
class HistoryViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
    private let search = UISearchBar()
    
    private var keyboardShown = false
    private var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    let historyControl = UISegmentedControl()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = "History"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(search)
        view.addSubview(historyControl)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.register(HistorySectionHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")

        search.delegate = self
        search.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        search.searchTextField.placeholder = "Search exercises"

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        historyControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        search.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let constraints = [
            search.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            search.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            search.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -16),

            historyControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: search.bottomAnchor),
            historyControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            historyControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -30),
            historyControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),

            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: historyControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ]

        bottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        bottomConstraint?.isActive = true

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(sender:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(sender:)),
            name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
        guard !keyboardShown else { return }
        let tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0

        keyboardShown.toggle()
        bottomConstraint?.constant = -keyboardSize.height + tabBarHeight
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        guard keyboardShown else { return }

        keyboardShown.toggle()
        bottomConstraint?.constant = 0
    }
}
```

Nothing too complicated there, I dont think. Very old-school setup.

I've tried pinning the `topAnchor` of the `UISearchBar` to the `topAnchor` of the `view` instead of the `safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor` but that just seems to put the large title between the segmented control and the tableview.

I've also tried adding them to the `UITableView.tableFooterView` but as expected, it doesn't remain at the top as you scroll up.

I've also tried setting the content offset of the scrollView back to 0 in the `scrollViewDidScroll` but that was janky as all hell and kept stuttering if I tried to scroll up quickly.

Wondering what you think would be the most elegant or quickest solution to this problem without over-cooking it too much.